# What What happened to the mesh display panel in blender 2.8?

Tags: mesh

Although I was looking for the "Mesh display" panel in blender 2.8 and I can't find it anywhere, I don't know if they moved it or they still don't put it or even if they put it, help

[image: Mesh Display panel show in this image]

Answer (score 3):

It's now called *Viewport Overlays* and located next to the viewport shading options.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much